# Laravel-medialibrary working with multiple databases

Tags: laravel

I have an issue with laravel-medialibrary and two different databases configured in our Laravel app.

We got two models :

**App\Models\User.php** using connection named 'mysql'

```php
<?php

namespace  App\Models;

use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model  implements HasMedia
{
    use InteractsWithMedia;
    protected $connection = 'mysql'
}
```

and

**App\Models\Classe.php** using connection named 'custom_database'

```php
<?php

namespace  App\Models;

use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Classe extends Model  implements HasMedia
{
    use InteractsWithMedia;
    protected $connection = 'custom_database'
}
```

Then I try to upload a file in my ClasseController :

```php
 $classe = Classe::find($request->id);
 return $classe->addMedia($request->file('file'))->toMediaCollection('academy', 'academy')->getUrl();
```

Laravel-medialibrary is always saving images in 'mysql' database :/

We tried to create a custom Media class but it doesn't work.

Do you have a solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you config multiple databases in `.env`?

Comment: I have two 'connections' in my database.php config file : https://i.imgur.com/C51vKb8.png

Comment: Any luck resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add $classe->setConnection('custom_database');

*If you need to customise the database connection further before fetching or adding media, use you can do $model->setConnection('landlord').*

[Spatie media library](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/advanced-usage/customising-database-connections)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34909963)